# Protractor element.click() throwing an exception

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

I was trying to figure out why `.click()` below was crashing protractor :

```
  this.clickSecondPanel = function () {      
    element(by.css('div.panels-gs.panel-top-two-gs')).click();
  }
```

until I changed the line to :

```
 element(by.css('div.panels-gs.panel-top-two-gs')).click;
```

where my spec.js looks something like :

```
var DataCardPage = require('./pageObjects/dataCard.page.js');
var dataCardPage = new DataCardPage();

describe('Clicking on the 2nd panel', function () {

  dataCardPage.clickSecondPanel();        
    it('Should select the 2nd test panel', function () {                
        expect(dataCardPage.getSecondPanelText()).toBe('TEST123');     
  });
```

In other places in my code, I use `.click()` (with parenths), so this is confusing to me.

The error is nasty:

```
 Started
[17:44:23] E/launcher - Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with    the page
: "window.angular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a  non-angu
lar page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can     interfe
re with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
```

Any advice appreciated...

Bob

Comment: Hmm does the test actually perform the click?  Or is it just no longer throwing the error?

Comment: I was kind of wondering that too. I'll verify tomorrow morning. And btw, if I set a browser.pause () and "repl" into cmd line mode, I can literally send the exact same line to the browser with success. I've clearly done something weird, or the Angular app suddenly acts strangely at this point. ..

Comment: Yea I can't imagine how it would click, it should definitely be `click()` as a function.  Only other thing I would say is try moving that `clickSecondPanel()` into the `it` block, not sure if that affects control flow? but looks suspicious by itself.  Otherwise, I'd look at the below answer and/or make sure `ng-app` is on the <body>, if not you need to specify `rootElement` elsewhere in your config.

Comment: @Gunderson - please post as your answer. BINGO. The it() block accepts that call just fine.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked!  I'll write up an answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this in the comments above, posting as an answer.

My suggestion was to try moving the `clickSecondPanel()` inside the `it` block.  It looked suspicious by itself just from a "best practice" perspective as I do not have any code that is outside of a jasmine function i.e. `it`, `beforeAll`, `afterAll` etc (don't even know where I learned that habit honestly).

It also seemed to effect the control flow and asynchronous execution so the `click()` event was triggering too soon.  This can be explained in part by [this documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) and/or this [blog post](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/17/asynchronous-testing-protractor-angular/)

Comment: Yeah, good catch! There is no control flow outside of `it()`, `before*` and `after*` functions.

Comment: @alecxe good to know, thanks.  Don't think I ever officially knew that, just had my code under `it` as a best practice :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `browser.ignoreSynchronization=true` at the begining of your test. May be the application that you are trying to automated does not contain angular in it.

Comment: I literally just moved `dataCardPage.clickSecondPanel();` into the `it()` section - and it worked. I also noticed afterwards that @Gunderson had already suggested that, so perhaps you influenced me without me even reading that. Post that as your answer, @Gunderson.